# Sometimes left click not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad

I just shifted from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 18.04 and sometimes the left click just stop working and then I have to restart the system. I found alot of questions asking that the left click isn't working but none of them mentioned that it only occures sometimes, so may be my problem is different.

After a few updates on Windows, left click of my touchpad stopped working however on mouse it worked perfectly.

Comment: is this a windows or Ubuntu problem?

Comment: Ubuntu problem.

Comment: When left-click stops working, can you please execute in terminal `evemu-record` *(it will list available HID devices, and prompt you for one to use. Choose the one with "touchpad" in its name)* — does anything appears there for using the left-click?

Answer (score 0):

Logout user (crlt+alt+del) then login again. That happens to me all the time but re logging in do the work.

Comment: This is correct, but shouldn't there be a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same problem. Sometimes the touch pad left click, physical left key, and external mouse left key don't work at the same time. It is disappointing.

Check the link below
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9a2erf/solution_left_mouse_button_suddenly_stopped/

Answer (score 0):

This remains a problem with Ubuntu 18.04.  Running on VirtualBox on OSX.
None of the solutions suggested here or elsewhere restore the mouse clicks.  Only a full powerdown and restart resolves it.  The evemu-record command does not report any mouse clicks -- even when they are working.  The device is "VirtualBox mouse integration".  Perhaps this is a VirtualBox problem.

Comment: Workaround when this happens on Ubuntu running on VirtualBox:  In the VM menu / Input, uncheck Mouse integration, then check it again.